# Create custom javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

Hi I want to create several function which work similar but use a slightly different value. I cannot change the parameters because **I use these for a callback** of a library. My first idea:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  f = function() {
    console.log(i);
  };
}
```

This obviously copies a refence of `i` to the function but I rather want to value at that time so that each function outputs a different value. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this way:

```
var f=[];    
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      f[i] = (function(index) {   
            return function() {          
                console.log("My value: " + index);
            } 
        })(i);
    }
```

working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ygYr/)

Comment: Have you check demo this will create 3 functions having different values (this idea come from "but use a slightly different value").